I want to find a smooth section of the map from the Stiefel manifold to the Grassmanian manifold
The following question is related to research I am doing on reinforcement learning on manifolds.
Let $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Stiefel manifold, i.e. the set of orthonormal ordered $k$-tuples of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Grassmannian manifold, i.e. the set of $k$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I want to find a smooth map that sends each $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to an orthonormal $k$-tuple of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that forms a basis for that subspace. The smoothness of the map is key.

Perhaps you want to do this locally?

A local solution is the best I can hope for (given Sammy Black's response), and would still be useful. Can you suggest one?

Assuming that you're looking for a section (mentioned in the title), i.e., a map $s: G_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\pi \circ s$ is the identity on $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then this is impossible. In fact, there's not even a continuous such section, let alone a smooth one.
Perhaps the example where this is easiest to see is the case $(n, k) = (2, 1)$, looking at lines through the origin in the plane. The Stiefel manifold is the circle of unit vectors, the Grassmanian manifold is the projective plane, and the bundle map $\pi: V_1(\mathbb{R}^2) \to G_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is diffeomorphic to the covering space $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^1$ with two point fibers, i.e., a principle $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundle.
To see why no such continuous section is possible, imagine a path $\gamma: [0, 1] \to G_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ given by $\gamma(t) = \operatorname{span}\{(\cos \pi t, \sin \pi t)\}$. This parametrizes a continuous family of lines rotating from angle $0$ to $\pi$, so it's actually a closed loop. When we lift this path to a map $\tilde{\gamma}: [0, 1] \to V_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, say beginning with the vector $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = (1, 0)$, there's a unique choice of basis vector for each $t \in [0, 1]$. There are only two choices for a unit vector spanning the given line, but there's no way to jump from one to the other. So once we start with a given vector, it determines this choice all the way around.
Why is this a problem? The starting and ending vectors are the same "downstairs" in the Grassmanian (projective line), but they're opposite "upstairs" in the Stiefel covering space (circle). In symbols, $s(\gamma(1)) = -s(\gamma(0)) = -s(\gamma(1))$, which is impossible for a unit vector. This is the essence of the double covering that describes the relationship between these two spaces in this bundle.

I see. So any map must be punctuated by discontinuities - this is unavoidable. Notwithstanding, I still need a practical solution for my applied problem. Can you suggest a map that is smooth everywhere except for at these inherent discontinuities? In practice, I will only use this map for a subset of points on the Grassmannain manifold, so it may even be possible to avoid the discontinuities (e.g. in your example, if I expect to encounter lines within a limited range of angles, I can choose my beginning vector to ensure these lines are far away from the discontinuities).

Oh yes, a local section is possible, and this usually goes under the phrase local trivialization of the bundle, and in this case, each fiber is a copy of the orthogonal group $O(k)$ (see this section of the wiki article on Stiefel manifolds). This means that locally, i.e., above some neighborhood $U$ of any "point" in $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the bundle is diffeomorphic to a product: $\pi^{-1}(U) \cong U \times O(k)$.

How to do this explicitly, in terms of coordinates, depends on how you're describing the subspaces in the Grassmanian (points in the base space). There are two standard ways to describe a vector subspace: (1) as a span of vectors, in which case the corresponding Stiefel frame is tautological; (2) as cut out by a system of equations, in which case more subtle (but standard to linear algebra) methods must be used to find a frame.

Some details. I have a neural network. I calculate the jacobian (derivative of network output with respect to input) and calculate the right singular vectors of the jacobian via SVD. The right singular vectors, a point in $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, map to a point in $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The point in $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can change for two reasons: 1) I change the network input, which changes the jacobian; 2) the network itself changes as its weights are updated during training. How can I convert my right singular vectors into an orthonormal basis such that my desire for local smoothness is satisfied?
